# How to create query of queries using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I'm trying to convert query of queries used in ColdFusion to LINQ and C#. The data come from data files, rather than from the database.

I converted the first query, but have no clue as to

1. how to use it to **query the second query**.
2. how to include **count(PDate) as DayCount** in the second query.

Below is the code using query of queries in ColdFusion:

```
First query
<cfquery name="qSorted" dbtype = "query">
    SELECT OA, CD,PDate,
    FROM dataQuery 
    GROUP BY CD,OA,PDate,       
</cfquery>

Second query
<cfquery name="qDayCount" dbtype = "query">
    SELECT OA, CD, count(PDate) as DayCount 
    FROM qSorted   // qSorted is from the first query.            
    GROUP BY 
    OA, CD
    ORDER BY 
    OA, CD
</cfquery>
```

Here's the **first converted LINQ** query, and it works fine:

```
var Rows = allData.SelectMany(u => u._rows.Select(t => new
{          
  OA = t[4],
  CD = t[5],
  PDate = t[0]              
}))
.GroupBy(x => new { x.CD, x.OA, x.PDate  })
.Select(g => new
{
  g.Key.OA,
  g.Key.CD,
  g.Key.PDate 
})
.ToList();
```

Here's the pseudo-code for the **second LINQ** query, which I need your assistance:

```
var RowsDayCount  = Rows //Is this correct? If not, how to do it?
.GroupBy(x => new { x.OA, x.PDate, x.CD, })
.Select(g => new
{
  g.Key.OA,
  g.Key.CD,
  g.Key.PDate,//PDate should be PDate.Distinct().Count() asDayCount    
  // See DayCount in cfquery name="qDayCount" above.
})
.OrderBy(u => u.OA)
.ThenBy(u => u.CD) 
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query origionally wasn't grouping on `PDate`, but your translation is.  That's wrong.  If you want to count the number of `PDates` for each `OA`/`CD` pair, you need to not group on `PDate`.  Once you've made that change, you can modify the `Select` to pull out all of the `PDate` values from the group, and count the distinct values.

```
.GroupBy(x => new { x.OA, x.CD, })
.Select(g => new
{
    g.Key.OA,
    g.Key.CD,
    DayCount = g.Select(item => item.PDate).Distinct().Count(),
})
```

Comment: Thanks for catching my mistake in the second query. The compiler complained after I added your code: g.Select(item => item.PDate).Distinct().Count(). Should it be DayCount = g.Select(x => x.ProcessDate).Distinct().Count()?

Comment: @user2142250 Not based on the code in your question.  In your question the property is `PDate`.  If your code is not actually what you have shown in your question, then I can't know what it should be.

Comment: sorry, it's DayCount =  g.Select(item => item.PDate).Distinct().Count().